# О литературной цензуре

Tags: общие-вопросы, поэзия

Здравствуйте, дорогие форумчане!
Сегодня слушала радио и подумала: а существует ли в России какая-то цензура для того, что поется с эстрады? Раньше все песни проходили специальные художественные комиссии, а есть ли что-то подобное для текстов песен (если это можно так назвать) сейчас?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Формально в России гражданской цензуры нет. Есть редактура, которая по тем или иным соображениям выпускает песни в эфир. Ещё есть Федеральный закон "О защите детей от информации, причиняющей вред их здоровью и развитию", запрещающий в дневное время исполнение произведений содержащих непотребную для детей информацию. Про непонятный в правоприменении закон "О запрете пропаганды педофилии и гомосексуализма", промолчу. Оба закона имеют карательный, а не предупредительный характер.

Answer (score 2):

В современной России цензура вполне есть. Есть несколько государственных органов, карающих за нецензурные (вообще, так или иначе нарушающие законы) высказывания (или "выпевания"). Например, ФАС (Антимонопольная служба). Или http://fapmc.ru/

Другое дело, что это не похоже на Советскую или царскую цензуру. Непохоже тем, что в старые времена была, если можно так выразиться, "пре-цензура" (просто никого "не пускали"). А сейчас - "пост-цензура". То есть продюсер может ради сиюминутной выгоды (дешёвого популизма)выпустить на экран (на сцену) какую угодно нецензурщину; но ПОТОМ это ему же боком вылезет: конкуренты толпой радостно побегут стучать во все инстанции, и у продюсера чиновники столько крови и денег высосут, что в следующий раз он серьёзно задумается, стоит ли такая овчинка выделки.

Поэтому, из-за постоянно висящей угрозы этой пост-цензуры, у всех производителей теле-шоу-попсы формируются мощные внутренние цензоры.

Comment: Антимонопольная служба тут ни при чем. Но ссылку Вы дали правильную.

Comment: Антимонопольная служба вступает в действие, когда в высказываниях содержится недобросовестная реклама (не связано с "нецензурщиной", но тоже цензура).

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос про то, что поется с эстрады, а заголовок о литературной цензуре... мда-с... Это чтобы как-то вписаться в тематику сайта? )

"Цензура", конечно, есть. В кавычках, потому что это не те *"художественные комиссии"*, о которых говорите Вы.

Во-первых, тематику песен, стиль артиста, репертуар сейчас определяют продюсеры. Не многие артисты имеют возможность петь что хочется. Во-вторых, организаторы  концертов тоже обычно следят за тем, что будет петься со сцены. Если концерт транслируют по телевидению - это еще один этап "цензуры".  
Кроме того, у любой радиостанции есть свой репертуар. Есть исполнители, песни которых ротируют постоянно, есть такие, которых ни за что на данную радиостанцию не пустят. Выбирайте радиостанцию по своему вкусу.

Но в целом, конечно, защитить свои глаза и уши от потока "культурной информации" все равно не получится. Даже пресловутые законы не помогут. А если не можете изменить ситуацию, измените свое отношение к ней.

Comment: Цензура - это система **государственного** контроля информации. То что вы описываете - это редактура, которая уже личное дело владельцев СМИ.Р

Comment: Так потому у меня и в кавычках. Вопрос-то был про "что-то подобное".

Comment: yupaz, большая просьба оставить свою манеру оскорблять спрашивающих. Каждый Ваш ответ обязательно содержит долю желчи. Как минимум, это неприятно.

Comment: Спрашивающий прав. yupaz, оставьте, пожалуйста, свой высокомерно-издевательский тон. Вы ничуть не лучше остальных пользователей этого форума. Если Вам что-то показалось неправильным в вопросе, скажите об этом в вежливой и деликатной форме. А если не умеете, то лучше промолчите.  
С надеждой на понимание,  
администратор

Comment: Уважаемый @Noble! Приношу Вам свои извинения, если мой комментарий показался для Вас оскорбительным. Поверьте, у меня не было намерения оскорблять Вас. Я надеялась, что закрывающая скобка в конце моей фразы даст Вам это понять.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, сейчас мало кого заботит содержание текстов песен. Порой они бывают весьма далеки от смысла и рифмы :(